# IntelliJ IDEA не может собрать проект при первой компиляции

Tags: java, компиляция, intellij-idea

Установил  IntelliJ IDEA 14, выбрал jdk 8. При компиляции программы

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

идет долгая загрузка, а точнее IntelliJ IDEA 14 не может собрать проект.

Пробовал переустанавливать jdk и IntelliJ IDEA 14, не помогает.  В общем, стоит на месте и все, хоть бы ошибку выдало.

Фото:

[image]

Comment: Intellij Idea где брали? Надеюсь качали с официального сайта?

Comment: @Vladimir991 да , с сайта официального.

Answer (score 1):

А Вы пробовали сначала выключить а потом включить? Я серьезно, у меня была один раз такая же проблема после установки насырую и простая перезагрузка помогла.

Можно попробовать посмотреть доступность папочки с кешами на запись или пересобрать с другим jdk, вдруг информация полезная появится

Comment: Пробовал это все делать. плюс нашел статью https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/cleaning-system-cache.html  все по ней сделал, очистил кеш в программе и перезагрузил, ничего не помогло . Как посмотреть доступность папки с кешом ?

Comment: В винде правой кнопкой на папку и снять галку ридонли если она там есть

Comment: тоже пробовал , ничего. Установил 12 версию все норм, работает. Ладно. Обида грусть=(

Comment: Возможно родная техподдержка поможет